# Did a baby named Netflix de Jesús get registered this year in Colombia?

Tags: social-media, colombia

I was recently sent this image via social media, claiming that a baby with given name Netflix de Jesús had been registered earlier this year in Colombia:

> [image]

This is not entirely an implausible claim, but it does sound just a liiiiittle bit too good to be true, and the first page of google hits ([example](https://www.clarin.com/tecnologia/bebe-netflix-jesus-rodriguez-nombres-raros-inspirados-companias-tecnologicas_0_B1Lk4lv1m.html), [example](https://peopleenespanol.com/celebridades/registran-bebe-netflix-de-jesus-colombia/), [example](http://www.aztecaamerica.com/notas/noticias/285422/netflix-de-jesus-rodriguez-si-aunque-no-lo-creas-es-el-nombre-de-un-nino-en-colombia), [example](https://www.20minutos.es/noticia/3351422/0/netflix-google-marcas-nombres-personas-america-latina/)) seems to be mid-range news outlets that are just riding on the (then-viral) image from social media.

Did this in fact happen? Or is it indeed too good to be true?

Comment: Well, although Clarín (Argentina) and 20 minutos (España), are high volume newspapers, both cited "EFE" News Agency (efe.com) as the source.

Answer (score 4):

It's Fake. There are no records in the local authorities database regarding this certification. And the form is not the one used for that kind of certifications.

https://consultasrc.registraduria.gov.co:28080/ProyectoSCCRC/

However, there are some other names found in Colombia (not Fake) like Jesucristo Hitler Paracelso Zeppelin, Batman Roberto, Deportivo Independiente Medellin (yes, a soccer team), and Rocky Rambo.

*Source:*
This article (in Spanish): 
https://colombiacheck.com/chequeos/es-falso-que-hayan-bautizado-un-colombiano-como-netflix-de-jesus